# How do i fix this error in c? declaration shadows a local variable

Tags: c

I am trying to get the number of cards the user wants to enter and ask the definition and term each time. I am wondering what I am doing wrong in the loop for `nameofcards` variable.

[image: screenshot compiler warning]

Thank you in advance

```
int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // check argc
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        // correct user
        printf("Usage: ./deck name\n");

        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        // create loop to check user key
        for (int loop = 0, n=0; loop < n; loop++)
        {
            if (!isalpha(argv[1][loop]))
            {
                //correct user
                printf("Usage: ./deck name");

                return 1;
            }
        }
    }

    FILE *fp ;
    // open file
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "w");
    // make the file name as the user input in the command line
    scanf("%s", argv[1]);

    int numberofcards = scanf("How many cards(includes definition nad term) do you need: \n");
    for ( int i = 0, numberofcards; i < numberofcards ; i++)
    {
        printf("Term: \n");
        printf("Definition: \n");
    }

    // close file
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for ( int i = 0, numberofcards; i < numberofcards ; i++)` What do you expect this to do? The previous scanf line is wrong too, check its definition.

Comment: move ", numberofcards" to the previous line as the last parameter of scanf with an ampersand infront

Comment: i changed the scanf line thank you for that! i am planning on to loop asking for the defintions and term the same number of times as how many cards they need.

Comment: `scanf("%s", argv[1]);` makes no sense at all. You are writing stdin input to `argv[1]` which you should not modify. And you later never read it.

Answer (score 1):

The error is shown because you are redeclaring the numberofcatds variable in your for loop

Fix is to remove numberofcards in the variable declaration part of your for loop

```
for ( int i = 0, numberofcards; ...
```

should be

```
for ( int i = 0; ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the problem with the shadowed variable: `scanf` returns the number of converted values, not the converted value(s).

The first argument is a format string, not something you want to put on screen.

Instead of

```
int numberofcards = scanf("How many cards(includes definition nad term) do you need: \n");
```

you need something like

```
scanf("%i", &numberofcards);
```

plus error handling.